# Is there a way to use minAreaRect from OpenCV with double?

Tags: c++, opencv, bounding-box

I'm working within a 3D environment and a camera so that I have some 3D coordinates on one side and playing around with OpenCV on the other side.

I need to find a minimal bounding rectangle to a polygon, considering 2D coordinates and would like to use OpenCV for that.

The issue is that my coordinates are represented in double.

I tried:

```
  std::vector<cv::Point2d> poly {{1.1, 2.2}, {3.3, 4.4}, {5.5, 6.6}, {7.7, 8.8}};
  cv::RotatedRect box = cv::minAreaRect(poly); // crashes here

  cv::Point2f corners[4];
  box.points(corners);
```

but got the following error:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (points.checkVector(2) >= 0 && (points.depth() == CV_32F || points.depth() == CV_32S)) in minAreaRect, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/imgproc/src/contours.cpp, line 1913

If I use some `Point` instead of `Point2d` the coordinates of the resulted rectangle are truncated

```
// narrowing conversions
std::vector<cv::Point2d> poly {{1.1, 2.2}, {3.3, 4.4}, {5.5, 6.6}, {7.7, 8.8}};
cv::RotatedRect box = cv::minAreaRect(poly);

cv::Point2f corners[4];
box.points(corners);
```

I'm not hundred percent sure if I'm using OpenCV the right way but I stumbled upon this and would like to avoid writing my own Rotating Calipers function.

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`minAreaRect` accepts only `Point` or `Point2f`, i.e. points of type `CV_32S` or `CV_32F`.

If `float` points have enough accuracy for you, you can use `Point2f` instead of `Point2d`:

```
std::vector<cv::Point2f> poly{ { 1.1f, 2.2f }, { 3.3f, 4.4f }, { 5.5f, 6.6f }, { 7.7f, 8.8f } };
cv::RotatedRect box = cv::minAreaRect(poly); // now it works!
```

Comment: Thank you, it works :)
So, in OpenCV the double are not floating values right ?

Comment: In C++, not only in OpenCV, `double` and `float` are floating point values, `double` are 64 bit, while `float` are 32 bit.